# How to split a tensor into a table of contiguous tensors in Torch?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, torch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to split a tensor and then use nn.ParallelTable to do some stuff on the split tensors. However, nn.SplitTable makes the split tensor non-contiguous and this is undesirable for me.

Here's my network architecture:

```
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (1) -> (2) -> output]
  (1): nn.SplitTable
  (2): nn.ParallelTable {
    input
      |`-> (1): nn.Sequential {
      |      [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> output]
      |      (1): nn.View(20, 1, 6, 6)
      |      (2): nn.SpatialConvolution(1 -> 10, 2x2)
      |      (3): nn.ReLU
      |    }
      |`-> (2): nn.Sequential {
      |      [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> output]
      |      (1): nn.View(20, 1, 6, 6)
      |      (2): nn.SpatialConvolution(1 -> 10, 2x2)
      |      (3): nn.ReLU
      |    }
       ... -> output
  }
```

And here's the code to produce it:

```
parallelLayer = nn.ParallelTable()
parallelLayer:add(nn.Sequential():add(nn.View(20, 1, 6, 6)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 10, 2, 2)):add(nn.ReLU()))
parallelLayer:add(nn.Sequential():add(nn.View(20, 1, 6, 6)):add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 10, 2, 2)):add(nn.ReLU()))

net = nn.Sequential():add(nn.SplitTable(2))
net:add(parallelLayer)
```

After doing the forward pass:
net:forward(torch.rand(20, 2, 6, 6))

I get the following error:

```
/home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:457: expecting a contiguous tensor
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/Tensor.lua:457: in function 'view'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/View.lua:83: in function </home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/View.lua:77>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:65: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function </home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:41>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:65: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ParallelTable.lua:12: in function </home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ParallelTable.lua:10>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Container.lua:65: in function 'rethrowErrors'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Sequential.lua:44: in function 'forward'
    [string "_RESULT={net:forward(torch.rand(20, 2, 6, 6))}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/amir/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651: in function 'repl'
    ...amir/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

But if I do:

```
net:get(2):forward({torch.rand(20, 6, 6), torch.rand(20, 6, 6)})
```

I do not get any errors. Does anyone have any ideas on how one can split an input tensor into contiguous tensors? Or maybe I should ask how I can split a tensor contiguously and then use ParallelTable? Is there any better approach to do this that I'm unaware of?